# spring jpa custom query to return page<E>

Tags: java, spring, jpa, pagination, repository

I'm trying to get pagination from the list that I have using jpa repository. List is actually attribute of another object. It is, sort of, kind off, message board... Long story short, Class Tiket has a list of Poruka that I want to retrieve and paginate them. Here is what it looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tiket")
public class Tiket implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="naslov")
    @NotEmpty(message= "Morate unijeti naslov tiketa")
    private String naslov;

    @Column(name = "tiket_datum")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @NotNull
    private Date tiketDatum;

    @Column(name = "rijesen_datum")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date rijesenDatum;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private Korisnik korisnik;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid-gen", strategy = "increment") 
    @CollectionId(columns = @Column(name = "collection_id"), generator = "uuid-gen", type = @Type(type = "long"))
    private List<Poruka> poruke = new ArrayList<Poruka>();
```

OK. List of Poruka is what I need. 
So I tried creating custom query in PorukaRepository that would get the list of Poruka paginated by doing it like this:

```
public interface PorukaRepository extends JpaRepository<Poruka, Long> {

    @Query("select t.poruke from Tiket t where t.id=?1")
    Page<Poruka> findAllPoruke(Long tid, Pageable pageable);
}
```

and receive following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as col_0_0_ from tiket2 tiket2x0_, tiket2_poruka poruke1_, poruka poruka2_ whe' at line 1
```

then tried changing query, as the database has tiket_poruka table, to this:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM poruka p where p.id IN (SELECT tp.poruke_id FROM tiket_poruka tp WHERE tp.tiket_id=?0)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Each time I receive following error during compilation:

```
No property find found for type ba.fit.vms.pojo.Poruka
```

then tried to put it in the TiketRepository... No luck. Then I added order by and sorting to my query, still no luck.

error this time is that it cannot convert from Tiket to Poruka

Of course, I can just retrieve the list and paginate it in my controller, but I want to learn and see if this is possible, as it seems logical. Do I need to create custom repository? Or just my query is wrong?

And here is the Poruka.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "poruka")
public class Poruka  implements Serializable{ //, Comparable<Poruka>

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="sadrzaj", length = 255)
    @NotEmpty(message= "Sadrzaj ne moze biti prazan")
    private String sadrzaj;

    @Column(name = "datum")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @NotNull
    private Date datum;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="korisnik_id", nullable=true)
    private Korisnik korisnik;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="prethodna_id", nullable=true)
    private Poruka prethodni;
```

Of course, classes are shown without getters and setters...

Comment: That is only going to work with a HQL not a SQL query. So your first sample should work if you set `nativeQuery` to false. I strongly suggest a read on the docs and the difference between HQL and SQL.

Comment: My mistake, actual query is without nativeQuery=true param. I'll edit it now. Error I get is different with HQL

Comment: Your query is wrong you are trying to return a list but your query expects a single instance, so it is never going to work like this. Post the `Poruka` class.

Comment: which one hql or native? or both? any suggestions on how to write it correctly?

Comment: With native paging isn't going to work they query is executed as is. As stated please add your `Poruka` class.

Comment: Done. Also, as you can probably reason from native query and from the Tiket class , it creates table tiket_poruka with three fields (collection_id, tiket_id, poruka_id)